# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because there is no current transaction

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask, transactions, connection

I created an AsyncTask class in which i write this part (onPreExecute and doInBackgrond methods):

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // Instantiate ProgressDialog and Set style to STYLE_HORIZONTAL
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    dialog.setMax(100);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setTitle("Update");
    dialog.setMessage("Download data. Please wait...");
    dialog.show();

    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    int count = 0;
    int numUsers = 0;
    db = new Database(context);
    SQLiteDatabase localDB = db.getWritableDatabase();

    try {   
        JSONArray UserJsonArray = connectAndCreateJsonArray(urls[0]);

        numUsers = UserJsonArray.length();

        localDB.beginTransaction();

        for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++) {
            JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) UserJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            localDB.insert("Users", null, getParsedUserEntry(jObj));

            count++;
            publishProgress(count * 100 / numUsers);
        }

        localDB.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();                
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Msg", "catch");
    } finally {
        localDB.endTransaction();
    }

    return numUsers+"";
}

private JSONArray connectAndCreateJsonArray(String url) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/file.json");
    request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";

        while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }

        jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringBuilder.toString());

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();                
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonArray;
}
```

I have always worked fine, but today after some modifies to other classes and after installing 2 package from Android SDK  Manager, it stopped to work.
(i installed Android SDK Build-Tools v20 and Android SDK Tools to version 23.0.5).

Now i get this error:
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because there is no current transaction**

Here is my LogCat:

```
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 31210
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because there is no current transaction.
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.throwIfNoTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:915)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:398)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:522)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at com.example.myapp.DownloadDataFromServer.doInBackground(DownloadDataFromServer.java:114)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at com.example.myapp.DownloadDataFromServer.doInBackground(DownloadDataFromServer.java:1)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-13 02:11:36.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31210):    ... 4 more
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.myapp.Main has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{420f12e8 V.E..... R....... 0,0-480,322} that was originally added here
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at com.example.myapp.DownloadDataFromServer.onPreExecute(DownloadDataFromServer.java:49)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at com.example.myapp.Main.onOptionsItemSelected(Main.java:151)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1065)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:177)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
10-13 02:11:37.765: E/WindowManager(31210):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

On line 49 there is this:

```
dialog.show();
```

Online 114 there is this:

```
localDB.endTransaction();
```

It is very strange... what could be the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could be hitting an exception before `beginTransaction`..move the `finally` to another `try` block inside

```
try {   
    JSONArray UserJsonArray = connectAndCreateJsonArray(urls[0]);
    numUsers = UserJsonArray.length();
    if (numUsers < 1) return numUsers + "";
    try {  
        localDB.beginTransaction();          
        for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++) {
            JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) UserJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            localDB.insert("Users", null, getParsedUserEntry(jObj));
           count++;
           publishProgress(count * 100 / numUsers);
        }
        localDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();                
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Msg", "catch");
    } catch (Exception e) { // everything else
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        localDB.endTransaction();
    }
} catch (Exception e) { // everything else
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This fix the exception but now nothing is written to local db. numUsers i always 0.

Comment: @smartmouse do you see any stacktrace...double check your `connectAndCreateJsonArray`

Comment: The fact is that this class worked fine till some hours ago. Then i made some minor changes in other classes and i installed some SDK new files, as i said before. Could be a SDK related problem?

Comment: @smartmouse hard to tell, could be your code changes too. If you are getting `numUsers` 0 i would check its code. you dont want to do any DB ops in that case anyways, so may be add a `return` if(numUsers == 0).

Comment: I think i solved, i had to double check `connectAndCreateJsonArray` method. Anyway, do you think i have to apply your try-finally suggestion that you told me in your answer?

Comment: @smartmouse is it in `connectAndCreateJsonArray` or with DB/illegalStateException; If it is with illegal state exception can you please update this question, if something else can you create new question with details i can check.

Comment: I updated my question, i hope you can find a solution.

Comment: @smartmouse can you please update the code snippet you use currently, i assume you check for numusers and have updated try-catch

Comment: Here is `connectAndCreateJsonArray` with Log.e lines http://pastebin.com/htztN8mq and here is the LogCat http://pastebin.com/iHVffnJr (the println error is not red as other times)

Answer (score 5):

what about

```
try{
  ...
} catch (Exception e) { // everything else
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(localDB != null && localDB.inTransation()){
         localDB.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

instead of " ... move the finally to another try block inside" ?

Answer (score 1):

I have an error like yours, here is my code:

```
try {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+DB_TABLEDOWNLOAD;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    //空双引号为原表没有的字段
    String temp = "";
    int existIconPath = cursor.getColumnIndex("iconPath");
    int existAudioID = cursor.getColumnIndex("audioID");

    if (existIconPath == -1 && existAudioID == -1){
        temp = "url, downed,total,path,name, audioTitle, audioFileID,\"\",\"\"";
    }else if (existIconPath == -1 && existAudioID != -1){//iconPath不存在
        temp = "url, downed,total,path,name, audioTitle, audioFileID,\"\",audioID";
    }else if (existIconPath != -1 && existAudioID == -1){//audioID不存在
        temp = "url, downed,total,path,name, audioTitle, audioFileID,iconPath,\"\"";
    }else {
        return;
    }

    db.beginTransaction();
    String tempTableName = "_temp_"+DB_TABLEDOWNLOAD;
    String sqlCreateTemp = " ALTER TABLE "+DB_TABLEDOWNLOAD+" RENAME TO "+tempTableName+";";
     db.execSQL(sqlCreateTemp);

     final String TB_TESTPAPERINFO_CREATE = "Create  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " 
                  + DB_TABLEDOWNLOAD
                  + "(url TEXT, downed TEXT,total TEXT,path TEXT,name TEXT, audioTitle TEXT, audioFileID TEXT,iconPath TEXT, audioID TEXT);";
     db.execSQL(TB_TESTPAPERINFO_CREATE);

     String sqlBackupData = "INSERT INTO "+DB_TABLEDOWNLOAD+" SELECT "+temp+" FROM "+tempTableName+";";
     db.execSQL(sqlBackupData);
     String sqlDrop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '"+tempTableName+"';";
     db.execSQL(sqlDrop);
     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

I use return before `db.beginTransaction()`, my code return before `beginTransaction`, but I `endTransaction` in `finally` . If you do not `beginTransaction` and `endTransaction`, the exception will appear.

Comment: so check your code about the db.beginTransaction and endTransaction.Hope  this  help you.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, if an exception occurs before `localDB.beginTransaction();` then the transaction will not be opened, and due to the fact that in finally block you are trying to close it, an `IllegalStateException` will be thrown (transaction has not been started).

Replace this code:

```
try {   
    JSONArray UserJsonArray = connectAndCreateJsonArray(urls[0]);
    numUsers = UserJsonArray.length();

    localDB.beginTransaction();

    for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++) {
        JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) UserJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        localDB.insert("Users", null, getParsedUserEntry(jObj));
        count++;
        publishProgress(count * 100 / numUsers);
    }

    localDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();                
} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("Msg", "catch");
} finally {
    localDB.endTransaction();
}
```

On this code:

```
JSONArray UserJsonArray = connectAndCreateJsonArray(urls[0]);
numUsers = UserJsonArray.length();

localDB.beginTransaction();

try {   
    for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++) {
        JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) UserJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        localDB.insert("Users", null, getParsedUserEntry(jObj));
        count++;
        publishProgress(count * 100 / numUsers);
    }

    localDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();                
} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("Msg", "catch");
} finally {
    localDB.endTransaction();
}
```

If necessary, the first two lines can be wrapped in a separate `try-catch`.